# PHP - Out of Memory while very simple loop, w/o object

Tags: php, out-of-memory

i have some trouble for a very simple loop because i goes out of memory and i really dont know why.
Hope someone will be able to help me.
Here is my code:

```
$full_list = array();
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
{
    $val = array_slice($line, 0, 1);
    $line = NULL;
    unset($line);
    if (in_array($val, $full_list) === FALSE)
        $full_list[] = $val;
    $val = NULL;
    unset($val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

I tried the $line = NULL && then unset it as u can see but even like that it doesnt work, if the file is too big i'll get out of memory...
To be honest, i dont even understand why the memory even increase during the loop....

Comment: You are filling the `$full_list` array.

Comment: i know but it's a simple array with just one column (string content at 254 char max)
How many row do i need to get out of memory ?
And i forget to say that i set the memory_limit at '-1'.

And more strange, if i do not check for duplicate (the if condition), and put everything on full_list... it does work, that's why i dont understand..

If i take full of the file it work, if i try to not take duplicate it doesnt work... i guess i have some leaks but i really cant see where ...

Comment: Iutput the memory usage after each iteration, compare that to the configured memory limits. Those `$foo = NULL; unset($foo);` are useless.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes i know about the NULL and unset but i was kind of desperate.... How do i do to output the memory usage, an echo ?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=find+memory+usage+in+php&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=find+memory+usage+in+php&sc=0-10&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=d7b7297fefcb4875ba21479f7e7886a6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you will always run out of memory, because, variable `$full_list` will always grow, till you will reach out of memory.

you need to do your stuff directly in `while` cycle.

and instead use `array_slice($line, 0, 1)` just use: `$line[0]`

Comment: yes but like i said:
-if i copy the whole file in full_list, it work well..
-if i try to filter duplicate (so full_list will be less big) it doesnt work cause i'm out of memory...

It's strange, no ?

Comment: no, because everytime you use in_array function. so solution will be to put them all. and after to use `array_unique`

Comment: other solution to use associative arrays:

`$full_list[$line[0]] = $line[0]`